# toggle() when home button click on slidingmenu with actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light_DarkActionBar); //Used for theme switching in samples
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Hide title bar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    //Enable home button
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    //Home as up display
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Sliding menu
    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(getBaseContext());
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.slide_menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {       
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //should be something in here that makes it slide to the left
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //Used to put dark icons on light action bar
    //boolean isLight = SampleList.THEME == R.style.Theme_Sherlock_Light;

    menu.add("New")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.contentnew)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    menu.add("Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.actionsearch)
        .setActionView(R.layout.collapsible_edittext)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

I want to set when home button is clicked, it slides to the left. Thing is, i can't extend `SlidingFragmentActivity` like examples in jfeinstein10's project, because i already extended `SherlockActivity`. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a change in the SlidingMenu code. Make `SlidingFragmentActivity` extend `SherlockFragmentActivity`. Then add ActionBarSherlock as library project to SlidingMenu. Now your project only has to add SlidingMenu as library project, because that references ActionBarSherlock.

Quoted from https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu#setup-with-actionbarsherlock:

> ## Setup with ActionBarSherlock
>
> - Setup as above.
> - Checkout a clean copy of ActionBarSherlock and import into your Eclipse workspace.
> - Add ActionBarSherlock as a dependency to SlidingMenu
> - Go into the SlidingActivities that you plan on using make them extend `Sherlock___Activity` instead of `___Activity`.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. Just want to be clear for anyone having  the same problem, in `SherlockFragmentActivity.java` (slidingmenue library) change `public class SlidingFragmentActivity extends SlidingActivity implements SlidingActivityBase {` to `public class SlidingFragmentActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements SlidingActivityBase {`

Answer (score 2):

You need to extend from SlidingFragmentActivity, If you don´t do it you can´t even call toggle or set the menu fragment.If you extended from SFA it would be something like this:

```
case android.R.id.home:
    toggle();
    return true;
```

Comment: If i extend `SlidingFragmentActivity`, how can i use sherlock actionbar?

Comment: You just repeat my question, what if i don't extend `SlidingFragmentActivity`, how can i achieve that?